# Can someone tell me what this means?

Tags: java

While working with threads and runnables, this popped up...Can someone please tell me what this means? Thank you so much.

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread

Comment: It's basically telling you that you cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a thread that is the EDT (event dispatcher thread). For whatever reason, the `EDT` needed to call `invokeAndWait()`, but either security, visibility, or some other cause did not let the `EDT` call the method. This exception was thrown from the AWT Event Queue Thread (0), which is the thread that manages `java.awt.*` classes.

Comment: It had nothing to do with security or visibility. The method's JavaDocs [clearly state](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeAndWait-java.lang.Runnable-): "This method will throw an Error if called from the event dispatcher thread."